# CSS - content area fill window

Tags: css

```
<div id="content">

</div>

#content{
height:100%;
z-index:2;
position:relative;
top:40px
}
```

This DIV is positioned 40px from the top of the page and scrolls under a nav 40px high positioned above it.

How can I make #content fill the rest of the window and not extend a further 40px like happens when using height:100%?

Note this the content div must be able to expand beyond the window height when enough content inside it is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `calc`, and want to only use css, do something like this:

```
#content {
    min-height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Check http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc to see if the browsers you are targeting support it.

Comment: Based on the last two lines of the OP question you may need to change height for min-height.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two options here.

- One using `calc()` <sub>[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/calc)</sub> :

  ```
   #content {
       min-height: calc(100% - 40px);
   }
  ```
- Two using `box-sizing` <sub>[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)</sub> and `padding` instead of `top`

  ```
   #content {
       padding-top:40px;
       min-height:100%;
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need javascript to calculate the correct height that you need, you can then use jquery like such to change your height:

```
$("#content").css('height','CALCULATED_VALUE');
```

All you need is to find out how many pixels you use for each line and multiply it by the lines you have to display.